# IDENTITY_INSERT issue with sql

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to populate an azure database, when i run the query :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT author ON

DECLARE @TEASER varchar(4000) = 'text..';
DECLARE @BODY varchar(4000) = 'text...';

insert into author(id,first_name,last_name,email) values (1,'Dan','Vega','danvega@gmail.com');
insert into author(id,first_name,last_name,email) values (2,'John','Smith','johnsmith@gmail.com');

insert into post(id,title,slug,teaser,body,author_id,posted_on) values (1,'Spring Boot Rocks!','spring-boot-rocks',@TEASER,@BODY,1,DEFAULT);
```

I have the error on the *insert into post* line : `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'post' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` After i run it the authors get created but not the post.

if i add both like **SET IDENTITY_INSERT author ON SET IDENTITY_INSERT Post ON** i have `IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'spring-boot-intro.dbo.author'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Post'`. . If i only add **SET IDENTITY_INSERT Post ON** i have `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'author' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF`.

Comment: "IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF" ... for `post`; you only enabled it for `author`

Comment: if i add both like `SET IDENTITY_INSERT author ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Post ON` i have **IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'spring-boot-intro.dbo.author'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'Post'.**  . If i only add `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Post ON` i have **Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'author' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.** . I edited them in in the post

Comment: Did you try turning off identity_insert for `author` before turning it on for `post`?

Comment: I don't think there such a thing as IDENTITY_INSERT in MySQL.

Comment: Maybe you need to execute the batch before running the insert.  Insert `GO` after `SET IDENTITY_INSERT author ON`

Answer (score 0):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.

from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql)

Comment: is IDENTITY_INSERT only possible in MSSQL ?

Comment: Not sure about other vendors, but MySQL (and I assume MariaDB) doesn't need it; you're allowed to insert into auto_increment fields whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by explicitly turning on and off IDENTITY_INSERT

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT author ON
*author insertions here*
SET IDENTITY_INSERT author OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT post ON
*post insertions here*
```

Comment: You should probably conclude the sequence with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT post OFF`; depending on the connection/environment these statements are being executed through, omitting it could cause hard to track issues; like an unrelated query being unable to enable it for an unrelated table (in a program that reuses a database connection).